# Express Simple Algorithm Mathematically

Tags: matrices, notation

I would like represent the following statement mathematically.

I have a matrix with m rows and n columns. I would like to do write, in mathematical notation, a function that does these two steps:

1. Normalize all columns so they sum to 100,000.
2. Divide all rows by the maximum value within that row.

How do I express this using mathematical notation?

Comment: Honestly? I wouldn't. There is no advantage to writing it in clumsy jargon-like notation when writing it in plain English is far more standard and far easier to read.

Comment: Column operations and row operations on matrices do not have any conventual notation that I know of. You are welcome to define your own and use it.